# Webpack, babel and react: Remove certain classnames from production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

In my project I use a special type of classNames starting with 'u-', e.g. 'u-title_bar', for unit tests. I'd like to remove them from the production build, is there a tool for doing that?

```
// MyComponent.jsx
// u-my_comp is just for unit testing. my_comp is for styling
const MyComponent = () => <div className="u-my_comp my_comp">My Component</div>

// MyComponent.test.jsx
expect(myComponent.find('.u-my_comp).text()).toEqual('My Component');

// Expected result after cleanup: 
<div className="my_comp">My Component</div>
```

Comment: How do the code that uses them look like? Are they used in React components or where?

Comment: @estus I added the example code.

Comment: @skyboyer I don't think they will be automatically removed if I don't do anything? Or?

Comment: sorry, my bad, I've misunderstood you like you were talking about classes(not class-names)

Comment: Ok, no worries :)

Comment: I don't know easy way to clean up specific class names keeping others but if you moved your test-oriented selectors into separate attribute you would be able to use [babel-plugin-react-remove-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-remove-properties)

Comment: Keep your unit testing code away from production

Comment: @DavidLemon well, that's what I'm trying to achieve here

Comment: @skyboyer That should work! Thanks :) You should write it into an answer. Just one thing I realized, wouldn't the tests break if I removed the locators? Or would the tests run before webpack does its job?

Comment: @XunYang yes, and this is not a good idea, unit tests are not for running in production.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm trying to remove it

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-remove-properties doesn't support regexps, so all properties should be listed explicitly, or it needs to be forked.

Comment: @estus I can probably use `data-test='u-my_comp'` and `myComponent.find('[data-test='u-my_comp')` to conduct the tests

Comment: @XunYang a good practice is having the test classes in another directory, run them in local or in another development enviroment. Then build the production bundle without the test directory.

Comment: @DavidLemon I'm not sure if we are talking about the same thing. But in the code samples, the line under `// MyComponent.jsx` and the one under `// MyComponent.test.jsx` are supposed to be 2 different files.

Comment: @XunYang yes, sorry I misunderstood you. For this I would have one configuration file for each enviroment and load it in the build pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

It would be possible to detect these class names only with custom Babel transform, and it would fail for dynamic class names.

In case it's needed to remove all `u-` classes, a helper should be created:

```
const prodClassNames = (...classNames) => classNames
  .reduce((classNames, className) => classNames.concat(className.split(/\s+/)), [])
  .filter(className => process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' || !/^u-/.test(className))
  .join(' ');
```

Can be used as:

```
<div className={prodClassNames('u-my_comp my_comp')}>My Component</div>
```

Or:

```
<div className={prodClassNames('u-my_comp', 'my_comp')}>My Component</div>
```